# Google Apps - Script executes another script without calling a function of it

Tags: google-apps-script, logging, execution

**Script01.gs**

```
function list_folders_with_no_files_and_subfolders() {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var folderNames = [];
  
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var files = subFolder.getFiles();
    var subFolders = subFolder.getFolders();

    if (files.hasNext()  || subFolders.hasNext()  ) { 
      continue;

    }

      var name = subFolder.getName();
      folderNames.push(name);
    
  }

  
  Logger.log("Log Script 01:");
  folderNames.forEach(function(name) {
    Logger.log(name);
  });
}
```

**Script02.gs**

```
function listAllFolders() {
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('YOUR_FOLDER_ID');
  var folderNamesToCheck = [];
  
  if (rootFolder) {
    var folders = rootFolder.getFolders();
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
      var subFolder = folders.next();
      folderNamesToCheck.push(subFolder);
      listSubFolders(subFolder, folderNamesToCheck);
    }
  }
  
  return folderNamesToCheck;
}



function listSubFolders(folder, folderNamesToCheck) {
  var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = subFolders.next();
    folderNamesToCheck.push(subFolder);
    listSubFolders(subFolder, folderNamesToCheck);
  }
}




function listEmptyFolders() {
  var emptyFolders = [];
  var folderNamesToCheck = listAllFolders();
  
  folderNamesToCheck.forEach(function(folder) {
    var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    
    if (!files.hasNext() && !subFolders.hasNext()) { 
      emptyFolders.push(folder.getName());
    }
  });
  
  return emptyFolders;
}





var emptyFolders = listEmptyFolders();
Logger.log("Log Script 02:");
Logger.log(emptyFolders);
```

When I execute Script01, I notice that the execution log displays the message "Log Script 02:" before showing the log messages from Script01.

However, when I execute Script02, I only see the message "Log Script 02:", which seems correct.

So what in Script01 triggers a function in Script02? All functions have unique names, and when I'm in Script01, the only function I can select is list_folders_with_no_files_and_subfolders, which is correct. But it still triggers something in Script02.

Thank you!

I expect to see only the execution log of Script01 (list_folders_with_no_files_and_subfolders) and nothing nothing from Script02.

Comment: How do you execute "script02.gs" or  "script01.gs"?

Comment: If script01.gs and script02.gs are in the same project then all of their functions are objects in global space.  You can see that if you run the debugger and look at global in the  debugger.

Comment: I don't know how to execute an entire gs file myself.  That's why I am asking.

Comment: I mentioned it incorrectly earlier. I don't execute an entire script, but rather a function within it. You're correct; both scripts are in the same project. In Script02, a few lines were not within a function and were therefore part of the global space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute Script01, execution log displays the message "Log Script 02:"
because

```
var emptyFolders = listEmptyFolders();
Logger.log("Log Script 02:");
Logger.log(emptyFolders);
```

are in global visibility, and first IDE run the function `listEmptyFolders()` and then it's your function `list_folders_with_no_files_and_subfolders()`

remove this

```
var emptyFolders = listEmptyFolders();
Logger.log("Log Script 02:");
Logger.log(emptyFolders);
```

from global visibility

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I got it. Thank you!!

The lines:

```
var emptyFolders = listEmptyFolders();
Logger.log("Log Script 02:");
Logger.log(emptyFolders);
```

are outside of any function definition, which means they are in the global scope. As a result, when Script01 runs, these lines of code are executed immediately, even before the main function `list_folders_with_no_files_and_subfolders()` is called.

I can remove it, like you said or do this:

```
function emptyFoldersToLog() {
  var emptyFolders = listEmptyFolders();
  Logger.log("Log Script 02:");
  Logger.log(emptyFolders);
}
```